# How to fix issue in Extjs when my app is RTL?

Tags: extjs

When I drop my panel in non drop zone the Extjs animate the drag element back to the source element in wrong directions, how to fix this behavior?
[image]

Here is my code for Dragzone and DropZone, when I change my app to LTR it just fine, and when I switch it back to RTL then the issue appears again.

```html
function calEventPnlSourceDD(sender){
  sender.mX=sender.getX();
  sender.dragZone = new Ext.dd.DragZone(sender.getEl(), {
        ddGroup: 'dgCal',
        getDragData: function(e) {
            var sourceEl = e.getTarget(sender.itemSelector, 10);
            if (sourceEl) {
                /*sourceEl=sourceEl.parentElement;*/                             
                d = sourceEl.cloneNode(true);
                d.id = Ext.id();
                return {
                    ddel: d,
                    sourceEl: sourceEl,
                    repairXY: Ext.fly(sourceEl).getXY()
                }
            }
        },
        getRepairXY: function() {
                return this.dragData.repairXY;
          },
        onDrag: function(e) {
        
        }
  });
}
function calEventPnlTargetDD(sender){
 sender.dropZone = new Ext.dd.DropZone(sender.el, {
        ddGroup: 'dgCal',
        isDropAllowed: false,
        getTargetFromEvent: function(e) {
            return e.getTarget(sender.rowSelector);
        },              
        getAllowed: function(e) {
            var proto = Ext.dd.DropZone.prototype;
            var tg=e.target;           
            this.isDropAllowed=true;  
            return proto.dropAllowed;
        },
        notifyOver: function(source,e,data) {           
            return this.getAllowed(e);
        },
        onNodeDrop: function(target, dd, e, data) {            
         return this.isDropAllowed;
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 9 days I found the cause of the problem, in my local file local-he.js I removed this line:

```
Ext.define('Ext.locale.container.Viewport',{override:'Ext.container.Viewport',requires:['Ext.rtl.*'],rtl:!0});
```

Because I already defined my app as RTL in UniMainModule.

I use Unigui framework with Delphi :-)